# I have a messy JSON that I am trying to clean up using jq

Tags: json, jq, data-manipulation

I have some messy JSON.

- Some nodes are not consistent across rows. In some rows these nodes are arrays and in some these are objects or strings.
- The example here is only two levels, but the actual data is nested many more levels.

Example:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "person": {
      "addresses": {
        "address": {
          "city": "FL"
        }
      },
      "phones": [
        {
          "type": "mobile",
          "number": "555-555-5555"
        }
      ],
      "email": [
        {
          "type": "work",
          "email": "john.doe@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          "type": "work",
          "email": "john.doe@work.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "person": {
      "addresses": [
        {
          "type": "home",
          "address": {
            "city": "FL"
          }
        }
      ],
      "phones": {
        "type": "mobile",
        "number": "555-555-5555"
      },
      "email": {
        "type": "work",
        "email": "jane.doe@gmail.com"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to make the nodes consistent so that if any the node is an array in any of the nodes, then the remaining nodes should be converted into arrays.

Once the data is consistent, it would be easier to analyze and restructure the data.

Expected result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "person": {
      "addresses": [
        {
          "address": {
            "city": "FL"
          }
        }
      ],
      "phones": [
        {
          "type": "mobile",
          "number": "555-555-5555"
        }
      ],
      "email": [
        {
          "type": "work",
          "email": "john.doe@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          "type": "work",
          "email": "john.doe@work.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "person": {
      "addresses": [
        {
          "type": "home",
          "address": {
            "city": "FL"
          }
        }
      ],
      "phones": [
        {
          "type": "mobile",
          "number": "555-555-5555"
        }
      ],
      "email": [
        {
          "type": "work",
          "email": "jane.doe@gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

After making the arrays consistent I would like to flatten the data so that objects are flattened out but the arrays remain arrays. This

Expected result

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "person.addresses": [
      {
        "address": {
          "city": "FL"
        }
      }
    ],
    "person.phones": [
      {
        "type": "mobile",
        "number": "555-555-5555"
      }
    ],
    "person.email": [
      {
        "type": "work",
        "email": "john.doe@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "type": "work",
        "email": "john.doe@work.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "person.addresses": [
      {
        "type": "home",
        "address": {
          "city": "FL"
        }
      }
    ],
    "person.phones": [
      {
        "type": "mobile",
        "number": "555-555-5555"
      }
    ],
    "person.email": [
      {
        "type": "work",
        "email": "jane.doe@gmail.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I was able to do this partially using jq. It works when there are one or two paths to be fixed, but when there are more than two it seems to break.

The approach I took

- Identify all possible paths
- Group and count the datatypes for each path
- Identify cases where there are mixed datatypes
- Sort the paths by decreasing depth
- Exclude paths that do not have mixed types
- Exclude paths where one of the mixed types is not an array
- For each path apply the fix on the original data
- This generates a stream containing N copies one for each N transformation
- Extract the last copy which should contain the cleaned result

[My Experiment so far](https://jqterm.com/0ad6d3000ec691596f702b29ca3698d1?query=def%20leaves%3A%0A%20%20if%20type%20%3D%3D%20%22object%22%20then%20.%5B%5D%20%7C%20leaves%20else%20.%20end%3B%0A%0Adef%20fix%28data%3B%20path%29%3A%0A%20%20data%20%7C%3D%20map%28.%20%7C%20getpath%28path%29%3F%3D%28%5Bgetpath%28path%29%3F%5D%7Cflatten%29%29%3B%0A%0Adef%20hist%3A%0A%20%20length%20as%20%24l%0A%20%20%7C%20group_by%20%28.%29%0A%20%20%7C%20map%28%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20%28.%7Clength%29%20as%20%24c%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20%7B%28.%5B0%5D%29%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22count%22%3A%20%24c%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22diff%22%3A%20%28%24l%20-%20%24c%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%7D%20%29%0A%20%20%7C%20%28length%3E1%29%20as%20%24mixed%0A%20%20%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22types%22%3A%20.%5B%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22count%22%3A%20%24l%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22mixed%22%3A%24mixed%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0Adef%20summary%3A%0A%20%20map%28%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20path%28..%29%20as%20%24p%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%3A%24p%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20getpath%28%24p%29%7Ctype%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20key%3A%24p%7Cjoin%28%22.%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%29%0A%20%20%7C%20flatten%0A%20%20%7C%20group_by%28.key%29%0A%20%20%7C%20map%28%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20key%3A%20.%5B0%5D.key%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%3A%20.%5B0%5D.path%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20depth%3A%20%28.%5B0%5D.path%7Clength%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%28%5B%28.%5B%5D%20%7C%20.type%29%5D%7Chist%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%0A%20%20%7C%20sort_by%28.depth%29%0A%20%20%7C%20reverse%3B%0A%0A.%20as%20%24data%0A%20%20%7C%20.%0A%20%20%7C%20summary%0A%20%20%7C%20map%28%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20select%28.type.mixed%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20select%28.type.types%7C%20keys%7C%20contains%28%5B%22array%22%5D%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20.path%29%0A%20%20%7C%20map%28.%20as%20%24path%20%7C%20%24data%20%7C%20fix%28%24data%3B%24path%29%29%0A%20%20%7C%20length%20as%20%24l%0A%20%20%7C%20.%5B%24l-1%5D%0A)

```
def fix(data; path):
  data |= map(. | getpath(path)?=([getpath(path)?]|flatten));

def hist:
  length as $l
  | group_by (.)
  | map( .
         | (.|length) as $c
         | {(.[0]):{
             "count": $c,
             "diff": ($l - $c)
           }} )
  | (length>1) as $mixed
  | {
      "types": .[],
      "count": $l,
      "mixed":$mixed
    };

def summary:
  map( .
       | path(..) as $p
       | {
           path:$p,
           type: getpath($p)|type,
           key:$p|join(".")
         }
     )
  | flatten
  | group_by(.key)
  | map( .
         | {
             key: .[0].key,
             path: .[0].path,
             depth: (.[0].path|length),
             type:([(.[] | .type)]|hist)
           }
       )
  | sort_by(.depth)
  | reverse;

. as $data
  | .
  | summary
  | map( . 
         | select(.type.mixed)
         | select(.type.types| keys| contains(["array"]))
         | .path)
  | map(. as $path | $data | fix($data;$path))
  | length as $l
  | .[$l-1]
```

Only the last conversion is present. I think the $data is not getting updated by my fix and this is probably the root cause, or maybe I am just doing this wrong.

[Here is e where this doesn't work](https://jqterm.com/fede7ad292fed3572335dfba417f117d?query=def%20leaves%3A%0A%20%20if%20type%20%3D%3D%20%22object%22%20then%20.%5B%5D%20%7C%20leaves%20else%20.%20end%3B%0A%0Adef%20fix%28data%3B%20path%29%3A%0A%20%20data%20%7C%3D%20map%28.%20%7C%20getpath%28path%29%3F%3D%28%5Bgetpath%28path%29%3F%5D%7Cflatten%29%29%3B%0A%0Adef%20hist%3A%0A%20%20length%20as%20%24l%0A%20%20%7C%20group_by%20%28.%29%0A%20%20%7C%20map%28%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20%28.%7Clength%29%20as%20%24c%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20%7B%28.%5B0%5D%29%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22count%22%3A%20%24c%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22diff%22%3A%20%28%24l%20-%20%24c%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%7D%20%29%0A%20%20%7C%20%28length%3E1%29%20as%20%24mixed%0A%20%20%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22types%22%3A%20.%5B%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22count%22%3A%20%24l%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22mixed%22%3A%24mixed%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0Adef%20summary%3A%0A%20%20map%28%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20path%28..%29%20as%20%24p%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%3A%24p%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20getpath%28%24p%29%7Ctype%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20key%3A%24p%7Cjoin%28%22.%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%29%0A%20%20%7C%20flatten%0A%20%20%7C%20group_by%28.key%29%0A%20%20%7C%20map%28%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20key%3A%20.%5B0%5D.key%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%3A%20.%5B0%5D.path%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20depth%3A%20%28.%5B0%5D.path%7Clength%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%28%5B%28.%5B%5D%20%7C%20.type%29%5D%7Chist%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%0A%20%20%7C%20sort_by%28.depth%29%0A%20%20%7C%20reverse%3B%0A%0A.%20as%20%24data%0A%20%20%7C%20.%0A%20%20%7C%20summary%0A%20%20%7C%20map%28%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20select%28.type.mixed%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20select%28.type.types%7C%20keys%7C%20contains%28%5B%22array%22%5D%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20.path%29%0A%20%20%7C%20map%28.%20as%20%24path%20%7C%20%24data%20%7C%20fix%28%24data%3B%24path%29%29%0A%20%20%7C%20length%20as%20%24l%0A%20%20%7C%20.%5B%24l-1%5D%0A)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following response first solves the first task, namely:

> make the nodes consistent so that if any ... node is an array in any of the nodes, then the remaining nodes should be converted into arrays.

in a generic way:

```
def paths_to_array:
  [paths as $path
   | select( any(.[]; (getpath($path[1:] )? | type) == "array"))
   | $path] ;

# If a path to a value in .[] is an array, 
# then ensure all corresponding values are also arrays
def make_uniform:
  reduce (paths_to_array[][1:]) as $path (.;
    map( (getpath($path)? // null) as $value
         | if $value and ($value|type != "array")
           then setpath($path; [$value])
           else . end )  ) ;

make_uniform
```

For the second task, let's define a utility function:

```
# Input is assumed to be an object:
def flatten_top_level_keys:
  [ to_entries[]
    | if (.value|type) == "object" 
      then .key as $k
      | (.value|to_entries)[] as $kv
      | {key: ($k + "." + $kv.key), value: $kv.value} 
      else .
      end ]
  | from_entries;
```

This can be used in conjunction with `walk/1` to achieve recursive
flattening.

In other words, the solution to the combined problem can be obtained
by:

```
make_uniform
| walk( if type == "object" then flatten_top_level_keys else . end )
```

### Efficiency

The above def of `make_uniform` suffers from an obvious efficiency issue in the line:

```
 reduce (paths_to_array[][1:]) as $path (.;
```

Using jq's `unique` would be one way to resolve it, but `unique` is implemented using a sort, which in this case introduces another inefficiency.  So let's use this old chestnut:

```
# bag of words
def bow(stream): 
  reduce stream as $word ({}; .[$word|tostring] += 1);
```

Now we can define `make_uniform` more efficiently:

```
def make_uniform:
  def uniques(s): bow(s) | keys_unsorted[] | fromjson;
  reduce uniques(paths_to_array[][1:]) as $path (.;
     map( (getpath($path)? // null) as $value
      | if $value and ($value|type != "array") 
        then setpath($path; [$value]) 
        else . end )  ) ;
```

Comment: Wow!. This is absolutely awesome. There is a semicolon missing in the definition of the function make_uniform, otherwise, this works perfectly. I like the way each step has been simplified. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using a bit of python along with the JQ scripts that [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak) had given in the solution above, I was able to clean up my messy data.

I still think that the answer given by [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak) is the right answer given the question I had asked. Although the solution is very good and works well, it took a lot of time to complete. The time taken depended on the number of nodes, depth of the nodes and the number or arrays it found.

I had two different files that I needed to fix and both had around 5000 rows of data. On one of them, the *jq* script took about 6 hours to complete and I had to terminate the other one after 16 hours.

The solution below builds on the original solution by using python and *jq* together to process some of the steps in parallel. Finding paths to arrays is still the most time-consuming part.

> setup
>   I split the scripts into the following

```
# paths_to_array.jq
def paths_to_array:
  [paths as $path
  | select( any(.[]; (getpath($path[1:] )? | type) == "array"))
  | $path[1:]]
  | unique
  | map(. | select([.[]|type]|contains(["number"])|not));
paths_to_array
```

> Minor adjustment to exclude any paths that had arrays in between. I just wanted all paths that end with arrays.
>   I also excluded the topmost array indices from the path to reduce the number of paths

```
# flatten.jq
def update_array($path):
  (getpath($path)? // null) as $value
    | (if $value and ($value|type != "array")
          then . as $data | (try (setpath($path; [$value]))
                    catch $data)
       else . end);

def make_uniform($paths):
  map( .
       | reduce($paths[]) as $path (
          . ; update_array($path)
         )
     );

# Input is assumed to be an object:
def flatten_top_level_keys:
  [ to_entries[]
    | if (.value|type) == "object"
      then .key as $k
      | (.value|to_entries)[] as $kv
      | {key: ($k + "." + $kv.key), value: $kv.value}
      else .
      end ]
  | from_entries;
```

> I had to add the walk function from [jq builtins](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq) because the jq library for pythonn didn't include it.
>   I split the make_uniform function so that I could understand the script better and I added a try catch because of an issue I encountered when the path included array indices in between. Otherwise this is pretty much same as the code from the original solution

```
# apply.jq
make_uniform({path})
| map( .
       | walk( if type == "object" then
                  flatten_top_level_keys
               else . end ))
```

> I had to split this because I was injecting the data for the path using the `{path}` and when this was in the full script I got an error when using `.format()` within python.

```py
import math
import os
import JSON
from jq import jq
import multiprocessing as mp

def get_script(filename):
    """Utility function to read the jq script"""

    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        script = f.read()
    return script

def get_data(filename):
    """Utility function to read json data from file"""

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data

def transform(script, data):
    """Wrapper to be used by the parallel processor"""

    return jq(script).transform(data)

def parallel_jq(script, data, rows=100, processes=8):
    """Executes the JQ script on data in parallel chuncks specified by rows"""

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=processes)

    size = math.ceil(len(data) / rows)
    segments = [pool.apply_async(transform,
                                 args=(script,
                                       data[index*rows:(index+1)*rows]))
                for index in range(size) ]

    result = []
    for seg in segments:
        result.extend(seg.get())
    return result

def get_paths_to_arrays(data, dest="data"):
    """Obtain the paths to arrays"""

    filename = os.path.join(dest, "paths_to_arrays.json")
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        paths = get_data(filename)
    else:
        script = get_script('jq/paths_to_array.jq')

        paths = parallel_jq(script, data)
        paths = jq("unique|sort_by(length)|reverse").transform(paths)

        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(paths, f, indent=2)
    return paths

def flatten(data, paths, dest="data"):
    """Make the arrays uniform and flatten the result"""

    filename = os.path.join(dest, "uniform_flat.json")

    script = get_script('jq/flatten.jq')
    script += "\n" + get_script('jq/apply.jq').format(path=json.dumps(paths))

    data = parallel_jq(script, data)

    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    entity = 'messy_data'

    sourcefile = os.path.join('data', entity+'.json')
    dest = os.path.join('data', entity)

    data =  get_data(sourcefile)

    # Finding paths with arrays
    paths = get_paths_to_arrays(data, dest)

    # Fixing array paths and flattening
    flatten(data, paths, dest)
```

As I mentioned before the get_paths_to_arrays does take quite long even with parallel processing.

- get_paths_to_arrays took 3811.834 seconds => Just over an hour.
- flatten took 38 seconds